# How to use decorator in the depend local typescript based node module with Create-React-App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I have a typescript based React project and it depends on another typescript based local project. I have such configs.

tsconfig.json of the React project:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-project": "file:../../Path/To/My/Project",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

If I use the decorator in the jsx file in the React project it would be fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function deco(target:any){}

@deco                   // < This would be fine
class test{}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, if I import a class from the external project with decorator it would fail when build:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
// This would case a error when build
import * as mylib from 'my-project/foo_module' 

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
/Path/To/My/Project/foo_module.ts 3:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders      
| import {deco} from 'deco';
|
> @deco()
| export class foo_class
```

It seems an issue about the webpack but I don't know how to handle this in Create-React-App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your package is exporting uncompiled typescript directly. Typically, compilers are not going to compile the output from dependencies because it expects that the dependent project has already done that. In My/Project, your `package.json` would have the `main` entry pointing to the compiled js, not the uncompiled ts:

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```